# how i can use this form 000-00-000 to input

Tags: java

the question 
write a program that reads in a line consisting of a student's name, social security number, user ID, and password(separat by one space). The program outputs the string in which all digits of the social security number, and all the characters in the password are replaced by x.( The social security number is in the form 000-00-000, and the user ID and password do not contain any spaces,and the name does not contain any digits.)

for example 
input :the user input : jimin 222-11-222 jimin22 jim2000
explanation: jimin is the name of user -should not contain any digits-
222-11-22 is social security number in form "000-00-000"
jimin22 is the user id
jim2000 is the user password

the output shoud be like
output: jimin xxx-xx-xxx jimin22 xxxxxxx

i dont know how the name making it without digits
and i dont know how output the social security number in form "000-00-000"

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      String name,So_n,ue_id,password;
      int x;
     ////to input
      name=input.next();
      So_n=input.next();
      ue_id=input.next();
      password=input.next();
      ///to output
      System.out.print(name+"\t");
      x = So_n.length();
      for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
          System.out.print("x"); }
          System.out.print("\t");
      System.out.print(ue_id+"\t");
      x = password.length();
      for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
          System.out.print("x"); }
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. What’s wrong with the current code? What’s a *chatterer*?

Comment: i want to social number is an int and replace by x in form xxx-xx-xxx and Other show message to user error.and the name just a character

Comment: Could you provide us some more Input and the corresponding Output please? It is really hard to understand your problem right now, maybe it is clearer with that data and we can help you.

Comment: When the social security number has always the form 000-00-0000 why not just print out xxx-xx-xxx instead?

Comment: @mayamar  I've thought about it but what if the user inserts numbers over 000-00-000 The program must send a wrong message

Comment: @J.Doe example : hala 77799997897 hala7h7 bts . hala is user name ok,and if the name is contain digits the program must view error massaga but i dont kno how  ** this is the problem ** , 77799997897 is social number  but is not in form 000-00-000 and is 11 number but the coreccet was 8 number in form 000-00-000  **that the problem with me** ,hala7h7 is user id ,and the bts is the password that well be xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that crux of the issue is to replace characters rather than just printing out some 'X' ones. Therefore, an approach that handles replacement would be most appropriate.

Here are a couple of sample methods that could address the OP's question. Additional methods to validate the user name, the password in terms of whatever complexity, etc., can be easily added. No details were provided on what to do in the event of an invalid input, so the one case here merely puts out a message.

```
// for a non-null password, return a String of the same length with all
//   of the characters set to an 'X'
public static String getObfuscatedPassword(String pw)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(pw, "Null pw input");
    return pw.replaceAll(".", "X");
}

// for a non-null ssn, return a String where every digit is replaced
//   by an 'X'; other characters (such as a -) are unchanged
public static String getObfuscatedSSN(String ssn)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(ssn, "Null ssn input");

    return ssn.replaceAll("[0-9]", "X");
}

// return true if the specified ssn is not null and
//   matches the format of ###-##-###
public static boolean isValidSSN(String ssn)
{
    // ensures there is something for us to validate
    //   NOTE: technically the .isEmpty is not needed
    if (ssn == null || ssn.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    // ensure in the format of ###-##-###
    return Pattern.matches("[\\d]{3}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{3}", ssn);
}

// returns true if the username has at least one character, and
//  no digits; does not prevent having spaces in the name (could
//  be added); uses a for loop rather than regular expressions for
//  a fun difference in approach
public static boolean isValidUsername(String name)
{
    boolean charFound = false;
    boolean digitFound = false;
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
        // check if the current name[i] is a letter or digit
        //  the OR will keep a true once it is set
        charFound = charFound || Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i));
        digitFound = digitFound || Character.isDigit(name.charAt(i));
    }

    return charFound && ! digitFound;
}
```

Driver example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String user = "jimin";
    String ssn = "222-11-222";
    String password = "WhatAWonderfulWorldItWouldBe";

    if (! isValidSSN(ssn)) {
        System.err.println("Invalid SSN");
    }

    String xdSsn = getObfuscatedSSN(ssn);

    String xdPw = getObfuscatedPassword(password);

    System.out.printf("%12s\t%s\t%s%n", user, xdSsn, xdPw);

}
```

Sample Output:

> ```
>   jimin   XXX-XX-XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

Using better variable names would be a good thing.

Some online example at: https://ideone.com/cPV2ob

Comment: thanks i have just one asking how i can make string without digits ?

Comment: @HalaHani, if your question is how to _detect_ digits in a String, I provided an example in `isValidUsername()` in the answer. If your question is how to remove them, then `String noDigits = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+","");`

Comment: When the user writ string with digits i want give massage to user error just

Comment: Adapt the method `isValidUsername(String)` as needed. It will return true if there are no digits, and false if there digits. By checking it, you can then give an error output.

Comment: Thank u very much , now i have just one asking how i can determined after second '-' the user must input 3 number just

Comment: This `isValidSSN()` already validates that. The format must be ###-##-### or else it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the digits in the SSO:

```
    x = So_n.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ('0' <= So_n.charAt(i) && So_n.charAt(i) <= '9') {
            System.out.print("x");
        } else {
            System.out.print(So_n.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: no that dont run cuz the So_n must be  in form 000-00-000